# Play! framework [1.2.4] war command failed

Tags: playframework

I need to export my play project to a WAR file but it failed. It does not work on a new project. Is this functionality broken?

Play! framework 1.2.4
JRE 1.6.0_20
I tested on both Windows XP and Linux.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

./play-1.2.4/play new testWar
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ The new application will be created in /testWar
~ What is the application name? [testWar]
~
~ OK, the application is created.
~ Start it with : play run testWar
~ Have fun!
~

play war testWar --deps --output=WAR --zip
sox: invalid option -- -
sox: invalid option -- e
sox: invalid option -- -
sox: invalid option -- o
sox: invalid option -- -
sox: invalid option -- z
sox: Can't open input file 'war': No such file or directory

play war testWar -o=WAR
sox: invalid option -- o
sox: invalid option -- =
sox: invalid option -- W
sox: invalid option -- R
sox: Can't open input file 'war': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try the following command:

```
play war youApplication --output yourApplication.war --zip
```

(i.e. do not add your `=` after `output`, and give a real `.war` filename)

Answer (score 2):

in the last two versions of Play!: 1.2.3 and 1.2.4, I use the following command:

```
play war MyPlayProjectName --o=MyPlayProjectName --zip
```

This will create two things:

1. Folder: MyPlayProjectName (extracted WAR file)
2. File:   MyPlayProjectName.war

I usually delete the folder and copy the war file to my TomCat server (webapps folder). This one works like a charm! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example , the systems "play" from sox sound utility is being run instead of the play frameworks "play" command.

The easiest solution is probably easiest to fix your path to match your frameworks "play" first.